# Query not working in laravel but working otherwise

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following query

```
select stock_data.symbol, open, high, low, close, oi from stock_data 
left join fo_data on fo_data.data_date = stock_data.data_date 
where stock_data.symbol='SYMBOL'
```

Symbol is the same column in both of the tables.
stock_data contains around 9 columns and fo_data contains around 70 columns.

Above query is working correctly in phpmyadmin but not in laravel, tried fluent query builder also.

**Edit**

```
$results = DB::table('stock_data')
        ->left_join('fo_data', 'stock_data.data_date', '=', 'fo_data.data_date')
        ->where('stock_data.symbol', '=', $symbol)
        ->where('stock_data.data_date', '>=', DB::raw("DATE_SUB('{$data_till}', INTERVAL {$months} MONTH)"))
        ->order_by('stock_data.data_date', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

If i comment this code out other code would work perfectly but if this code is present then the page returned is blank (not 404)

**Edit**

I increased the memory limt now it's showing results. My query was quite wrong and it was returning more than 5000000 rows, so that must be the problem.

Comment: How did you try? Where's the code? What's the error?

Comment: 1. The two queries above aren't same. 2. Give the whole function. Not just the builder.

Comment: Enable error reporting so you can see the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DB::query` to issue complex arbitrary queries that doesn't go well with the builder.

You can also use `DB::connection()->pdo` to access the underlying PDO object and try mannually from it.

see this: http://laravel.com/docs/database/raw

Also, try to put your identifiers between backticks. ex:

```
select `id` from `users`
```

This is because you may have hit some of the database's reserved words. PhpMyAdmin may be doing this for you and that's why you're not getting errors there. Just a theory.

Comment: I tried the sql query with DB::query too, but nothing was returned and it just does not let anything render on the page.

Comment: Error reporting was already on. This was in the start.php file
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I update my answer. Try escaping the identifiers...but you're really getting a blank screen? Check your laravel configurations and php.ini too, because that's just weird.

Comment: I increased the memory limt now it's showing results. My query was quite wrong and it was returning more than 5000000 rows. Thanks for the helping.

Comment: A word of advice. Always use try catch block while querying. In production.